# Passing and binding img src from props in Vue.js

Tags: image, vue.js

I am trying to display an image with the img tag by using a path from props for the src attribute.

I've tried changing the path with `@`, using the whole path with `src`, adding `../assets/` in the component and only passing the file name (`orange.png`) as props.
I always get the default broken image displayed.
When inspecting in the browser, the path seems fine.
When I display the image directly, I can see that the path is resolved to some different path `<img data-v-1212d7a4="" src="/img/orange.7b71a54c.png">`.

---

*Edit:*
Additionally I tried this post [Can't dynamically pass relative src path for imgs in Vue.js + webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906807/cant-dynamically-pass-relative-src-path-for-imgs-in-vue-js-webpack?rq=1) ,
where using `<img :src="require(picture_src)" />` is given as an answer.
This leads to an error: `Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/orange.png'"`

(*Edit2:*
This answer in the end worked for me in the end as described in my answer post.)
The same error occurs with the similar webpack method using `let images = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.png$/)` in my script part, as the answer on this post [Can't dynamically pass relative src path for imgs in Vue.js + webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906807/cant-dynamically-pass-relative-src-path-for-imgs-in-vue-js-webpack?rq=1) .

---

I am new to Vue.js, so I don't exactly know what is happening or how to search for this or it might not have anything to do with what I'm originally trying.

I am able to display my image when I pass the path directly, like this

```html
<img src="../assets/orange.png"/>
```

Now I'd actually like to pass it to my component in the props and then, inside the component, display it reading the path from props.

Component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src=picture_src />
    <div class="pic_sub">{{pic_desc}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'PictureCard',
  props: {
    picture_src: String,
    pic_desc: String
  }
}
</script>
```

Using the component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <PictureCard pic_desc='some description text' picture_src='../assets/orange.png' />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import PictureCard from './components/PictureCard.vue'
export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    PictureCard
  }
}
</script>
```

If it is possible, I'd love to display my from a path that is passed through the component's props.

Otherwise I'd love to know some other solutions, work-arounds or knowledge on best practices in this case.

Comment: How about passing the image directly, instead of source string? For example import the image in your Main Component and pass it in PicutureCard?

Comment: This question comes up a lot. The easy fix is to use `:src="require(picture_src)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js - Trying to bind dynamic images... what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49901191/vue-js-trying-to-bind-dynamic-images-what-should-i-do) and [Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working)

Comment: Prob the best practice here is to create new Image with js and use url from props

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. When I try to use `:src="require(picture_src)"` I get an error and the whole component doesn't render anymore. `Error in render: "Error: Cannot find module '../assets/orange.png'"`

Comment: What do you mean by importing the image or creating new image with js?

Comment: Your path is probably incorrect (relative to the `PictureCard` component). Try binding `@/assets/orange.png`. Another problem might be that you do not have the file-loader or its not configured for `.png` images though this should not be the case for a project built using Vue CLI v3.

Comment: I think the path should be correct since I use the same path that displays the picture when I use it directly in the src attribute. (Or that would be wrong?)

I'm not sure how/where to check configurations for the file-loader. 

Thank you for your answers. It helped me research in the right direction and posted what worked for me and why below.

Comment: In short, We can alter transformAssetUrls option of Vue loader to archive this. Can refer to my answer to another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72877371/1280871

Answer (score 43):

This worked for me

```
<img :src="require(`@/assets/img/${filename}`)">
```

where `filename` is passed in as a String prop e.g. `"myImage.png"`.

Make sure you use the path specific to your project.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/450

> *Note:* `@` is a webpack alias for `/src` that is set by default in Vue projects

Comment: I get: 'ReferenceError: require is not defined' when running the Vue app in browser.

Answer (score 11):

### **Newer solution:**

*The 'require()'-method does not work when using Vite.*

*I got this error: **ReferenceError: require is not defined.***

---

**This is how I solved it without 'require()' and with composition API:**

From parent component:

```
<ChildComponent icon-filename="icon.svg" />
```

ChildComponent:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="getImageUrl()">
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {defineProps} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  iconFilename: String
})

function getImageUrl() {
  // This path must be correct for your file
  return new URL(`../assets/icons/${props.iconFilename}`, import.meta.url)
}

</script>
```

Comment: Worked for me (nuxt3/vue3). But do you know what "import.meta.url" means ?

Comment: I think its a definition for formatting of the URL string. Docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta

Answer (score 5):

After some research, I understand that my problem has to do with webpack and resolving filepaths. I used a modified version from this answer:
[Vue.js dynamic images not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491506/vue-js-dynamic-images-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1)
and this answer:
[Can't dynamically pass relative src path for imgs in Vue.js + webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906807/cant-dynamically-pass-relative-src-path-for-imgs-in-vue-js-webpack?rq=1)
Since the link in the second answer was dead, here's an active link to `require.context` documentation:
https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext

My mistake when trying the second link's answer was that I returned only `orange.png` as the path, while I needed to add `./` at the beginning.

My working picture component now looks like this.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="resolve_img_url(picture_src)" />
    <div class="pic_sub">{{pic_desc}}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'PictureCard',
  props: {
    picture_src: String,
    pic_desc: String
  },
  methods: {
    resolve_img_url: function (path) {
      let images = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.png$|\.jpg$/)
      return images("./"+path)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I edited the regular expression to match `.png` and `.jpg` file endings. Therefore passing the prop looks like this now

```html
<PictureCard  picture_src='orange.png' pic_desc='some picture description'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

**This works for me:**

This is how i use my Componenent.

```
<image-element 
  :imageSource="require('@/assets/images/logo.svg')">
</image-element>
```

My Image Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   ...
     <img v-bind:src=imageSource />
   ...
  </div>   
</template>

<script lang="ts">
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import { Component, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

 @Component({
   components: {
    .....
   }
 })
 export default class extends Vue {
  ...
  @Prop({ default: '' }) imageSource!: String
  ...
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my favorite super simple way to do it. It can easily be reused in any file in any folder in my project. Just pass the actual path as a string from the perspective of the parent:

```
//some file
    <ParentA>
      <ImageComponent 
         myImagePath="../../../../../myCat.png"
      />
    </ParentA>

//some other file in a different folder in my project
    <ParentB>
      <ImageComponent 
         myImagePath="../../myCat.png"
      />
    </ParentB>


//child component file
<template functional>
   <div>
      <img :src="props.myImagePath">
   </div>
</template
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats all not working for me :D

The template File is wrong!
you need to add ":" before you set your prop.

thats how i should use the PictureCard

```
<PictureCard  :picture_src="require('orange.png')"
 pic_desc='some picture description'/>
```

and thats how my PictureCard should look like:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img v-bind:src="picture_src" />
  </div>
</template>

export default class PictureCard extends Vue {

@Prop({ default: require("@/assets/orange.svg") }) img!: string
 }
```

so in case no prop is setted, so i added a default prop too.
and yes i only used the image.